# Why this Swing login form is shown wrong?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am pretty new in Java **Swing** and I have a problem.

I have to create a login windows taking inspiration from something like this immage (something like this, scilicet the windows must show 2 text fields where the user insert its username and its password and a button to perform the login operation):

[image]

Ok, I think that this is pretty simple and I have realized the following class that do it:

```
package com.techub.crystalice.gui.login;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;

import com.techub.crystalice.gui.Constants;
import com.techub.crystalice.gui.GUI;

public class LoginFrame extends SingleFrameApplication {
    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> startup()");


        this.getMainFrame().setTitle("MyApplication Login");
        this.getMainFrame().setSize(600, 350);          // Setta le dimensioni del JFrame che rappresenta la finestra principale
        Container mainContainer = this.getMainFrame().getContentPane();     // Recupera l'oggetto Container del JFrame

        // Imposta un layput manager di tipo GridLayout per il contenitore principale: 3 righe ed una singola colonna:
        mainContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));   

        // Contenitore rappresentato da 6 righe a singola colonna contenente i campi testuali e di input del login: 
        JPanel body = new JPanel();
        body.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));
        body.add(new JLabel("Username"));

        JTextField userName = new JTextField();
        body.add(userName);

        body.add(new JLabel("Password"));
        JTextField password = new JTextField();
        body.add(password);

        this.getMainFrame().add(body);      // Aggiunge al JFrame principale il JPanel contenente il form di login


        show(this.getMainFrame());

        JPanel footer = new JPanel();
        footer.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER)); 

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        footer.add(loginButton);

        this.getMainFrame().add(footer);    // Aggiunge al JFrame principale il JPanel contenente il bottone di login

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> main()");
        launch(LoginFrame.class, args);
    }

}
```

This class use a litle framework named **JDesktop** that involves the definition of the **startup()** method but this is pure Swing code. The only thing to say is that I obtain the main **JFrame ** by this code line:

```
this.getMainFrame()
```

This example seems to work but I have some aesthetics problems in the login form visualization because I obtain the following result:

[image]

As you can see this is very nasty and also if the structure is the same of the example have some problems as:

1. The height of the **JTextField** is too small
2. There is not top, left, right margin between my elements
3. The font is too small

Can I correct this errors in some way? Can you help me give me some suggestions? The structure of my windows is ok?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: use GridBagLayout instead of GridLayout(6, 1).

Comment: that code `new GridLayout(6, 1)` will cause you aesthetic problems.

Comment: It seems strange to me...I am following this tutorial and here there is no problem using GridLayout: http://www.html.it/articoli/price-extractor-jpanel-e-jbutton/

Answer (score 1):

1. `this.getMainFrame().pack()` should be used to set the size of the `JFrame` to the minimum size required to display all the components.
2. I would suggest `GridBagLayout` because `GridBagConstraints` allow you to specify `Insets` which is spacing between the components and also allow you to position components properly.
3. Use the `java.awt.Font` object to set a desired font of appropriate size.  Keep a reference to your two `JLabel`s and then use the `setFont()` to set a proper font.

Answer (score 0):

The GridLayout component doesn't honor the hosted component preferred size (which is what you would like to have). The trick in this case is to add a JPanel(which honors the preferred size) with a JTextField inside so basically at the moment you have

JLabel
JTextField
JLabel
JTextField

after

JPanel (with JLabel)
JPanel (with JTextField)
JPanel (with JLabel)
JPanel (with JTextField)